# How to use timestamps for seeking in .m2ts files?

Tags: timestamp, low-level, mpeg, mpeg2-ts, transport-stream

I have .m2ts video file (VBR, duration = 1 hour). 
**I need to know from which byte I should read this file if I want to start playing this file from 20 minute.**
M2TS is standard TS with a 4-byte timestamp ahead of the sync byte (0x47), but I don't understand how use it. Please see following timestamps ahead of sync byte in my video file:
0D 9E E2 02
35 8B 62 28
1D 77 E2 4F
05 64 62 76
2D 50 E2 9C
15 3D 62 C3
3D 29 E2 E9
25 16 63 10
 **Can someone explain how to use timestamps for seeking in .m2ts files ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`M2TS` **doesn't have** a 4-byte timestamp.

What it does have is a 4-byte `TP_extra_header` consisting of a `2-bit` copy permission indicator plus a `30-bit` arrival timestamp (ATS) with a resolution of `27 MHz`.

```
    0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   | C |                         ATS                               |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                                                               |
   |                       TS [188 bytes]                          |
   |                                                               |
   | . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
```

Since the `BDAV` format is intended for storage, it uses variable rate (VBR) Transport Streams instead of the typical constant rate (CBR) streams found in broadcast to save space. The arrival time is recorded in order to be able to [convert the variable stream into a constant rate](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?p=888381#post888381) and T-STD compliant one for playback.

This timestamp will roll-over every `(2^30 - 1) / 27000000 ~= 39.768` seconds.

For eg: `1D77E24F ∧ 3FFFFFFF` is in decimal `494395983 / 27000000 ~= 18.32` seconds.

I'm not really familiar with BD but I think more info about the `m2ts` files is kept in the `clpi` and `mpls` accompanying files. If you only have the `m2ts` file you'll have to seek by PCR.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!